# Android CFW (Custom Firmware) SDK

Tags: android

I have a Samsung smdkv210 board (Haipad M7 I think) tablet and I want to deploy my hand-baked Android into it. Although I have read the official documentation from google regarding "repo"ing and "lunch"ing with according device names, I just can't be sure whether I am tracking the correct route. There are some CFW's on the net ( http://leeyuentuen.byethost15.com/blog/?p=1667 ) and I succeed to deploy 0918_CFW_M7_rooted.zip successfully, but I still lack the SDK to do it myself. May you shed a light?